# Polar coordinates on $\mathbb{S}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $n=(0,...,0,1)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $s=-n$ the north and south pole and for $x=(x^1,...,x^{n+1})$ define $r(x)\in (0,\pi)$ and $\theta(x)\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ by $\cos(r(x))=x^{n+1}$ and $\theta(x)=|x^\prime|^{-1}x^\prime$, where $x^\prime=(x^1,...,x^n)$.

Show that the mapping
$$\mathbb{S}^n\setminus\{n,s\}\to (0,\pi)\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1},\quad x\mapsto (r(x),\theta(x))
$$
is a Riemannian isometry of the manifolds $\mathbb{S}^{n}\setminus\{n,s\}$ and $(0,\pi)\otimes_\psi \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, where $\psi(r)=\sin(r)$.

Or short: $g_{\mathbb{S}^n}=(dr)^2+\sin^2(r) g_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$. I have seen the proof for the polar coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which tells you that $g_{\mathbb{R}^n}=(dr)^2+r^2 g_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$. This proof uses the projection maps $\pi^i$ on $(0,\infty)\times \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and shows a relation to the metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ but I don't see, how to use this here. Frankly, I don't see any way how to begin here.

Comment: The indexing is not quite OK (the $r(x)$ component is indexed last, but listed first), but that aside, can you see what's happening when $n = 2$?

Comment: Yes, I can see what happens when $n=2$. I think, the indexing is ok. The last coordinate of the spherical coordinates coincides with the condition on $r(x)$, I think. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: It looks to me that the mapping takes values in $S^{n-1} \times(0,\pi)$, and is given by $x\mapsto(\theta(x),r(x))$...? <> Whether or no, this isn't geometrically important; the point is that this mapping parametrizes $S^n$ with the two poles removed, slices $S^{n-1}\times\{r\}$ are shrunk by a factor $\sin r$, and the "profile" semicircle is traced at uit speed.